# What mechanism would degenerate gametes of select allosome?

Tags: genetics, reproduction

**I am looking for a mechanism that would cause ovum containing a specific allosome to degenerate before they could form a zygote.**

More detailed background: I am trying to design a unique method of what [I learned](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/65238) is called diploid arrhenotoky. Males and females are both diploid, but males are only produced parthenogenically.

Arrhenotoky produces diploid females and haploid/parahaploid males, not true diploid males. Haploid individuals can't carry two alleles and that complicates Mendelian inheritance.

The Z/W or Z/0 system works differently: ZW/Z0 zygotes become female, ZZ zygotes male; male produces Z sperm while female produces Z and W/0 ovum or ZZ and WW/00 (non-viable) zygotes under facultative parthenogenesis.

The only way I can think of to keep male zygotes from being conceived sexually is to make them non-viable somehow... I have no idea *how* to keep Z ovum from becoming viable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In biology weird things happen. For example, many animal species and *very* many plant species are tetraploid, hexaploid, octoploid etc. In plants it is even common to have the species of a genus share basic genomes combined in various ways; for example see the [Triangle of U](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_of_U) which interconnects the members of genus *Brassica* (cabbage and rapeseed), or the [genetics of wheat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wheat#Genetics) (*Triticum*). So if the species is tetraploid, hexaploid or octoploid the "haploid" males will be diploid, triploid or tetraploid and could carry two, three or four alleles for each locus.

As for the mechanism of rendering the sexually-conceived ZZ deleterious you could use an almost imperceptible handwave and say that a Z ovum cannot be fertilized by a Z spermatozoon due to [cytoplasmic incompatibility](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cytoplasmic_incompatibility).

And Mendelian inheritance is overrated anyway.

Comment: This is possibly the best question/answer pair that I just don't understand.